# Error when querying using JDBC SQL server connection

Tags: java, sql-server

I query data using the below code:

```
tBPMDataSource = getJndiDataSource("java:/NaNaDS");
tBPMConnection = tBPMDataSource.getConnection();
tBPMStatement=tBPMConnection.createStatement();
if (tBPMDataSource!=null) 
{
    tBPMResultSet = tBPMStatement.executeQuery("select OID from ProcessInstance where serialNumber='"+ProcessSerial+"'");
    while (tBPMResultSet.next()) {
        ProcessOID=tBPMResultSet.getString(0);
        }
}
```

And error occured,below is the error log

```
   2019-05-27 14:44:07,616 FINE  [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException] (default task-96) *** SQLException:com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement@2b71098e com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: ̷ӽ 0 ӬԶ׶Χc ̷ӽ 0 ӬԶ׶Χc
```

Can anyone help on ow to find the error code of this exception? I tried to excute the query in sql server and it worked fine. Thx.

Comment: Are you sure that the jndi resource exists? can you post the entire stacktrace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JDBC API the column indexes would be base-1 instead of base-0 like you were expecting.
I wish all index-related methods were base-0 for consistency reasons. It is kind of annoying to have to remember which methods use 0 and which use 1.

Answer (score 0):

in Java column index starts from 1. Try changing this line

```
tBPMResultSet.getString(1);
```

Comment: Don't say "in Java" because the starting index 1 is a special feature of a `ResultSet`. Java usually has 0-based indexes.